# React pass onclick data to other element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need help.. i just new in this programming and this react..
below is my code i been attached..

I wan the output is when button click onClick, the data will pass to other element that display the fakeData which is MOP, code, date, status.

Can anyone please tell me what should i do for next step and give me the correct answer for my problem..

thx for your help..

```
const fakeData = [
  {
    MOP: '(MOP 1196.00)',
    code: '#18102100-001',
    date: '10-08-2018',
    status: 'Pending Order',
  },
  {
    MOP: '(MOP 349.00)',
    code: '#18101900-001',
    date: '11-09-2018',
    status: 'Paid',
  },
];

export class TransactionPage extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, intl } = this.props;
    const formatted = fakeData.map(item => (
      <React.Fragment key={item.code}>
        <ListItem
          button
          className={classes.displayBlock}
          name="transaction"
        >
          <ListItemText className={classes.disablePadding} primary={item.MOP} />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.disablePadding}
            secondary={item.code}
          />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.disablePadding}
            secondary={item.date}
          />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.disablePadding}
            secondary={item.status}
          />
          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
            <ArrowIcon />
          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
    return (
      <Page>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.header })}</title>
          <meta
            name="description"
            content={<FormattedMessage {...messages.meta} />}
          />
        </Helmet>
        <PageContent>
          <Paper>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={5} md={4} lg={3}>
                <List className={classes.list} disablePadding>
                  {formatted}
                </List>
              </Grid>

              <Hidden xsDown>
                <Grid item sm={7} md={8} lg={9}>
                  <Grid
                    container
                    direction="column"
                    spacing={16}
                    className={classes.details}
                  >
                    <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.center} />
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Typography variant="h6">
                        CREDIT DEBIT
                      </Typography>
    //--------- I WANT THE DATE SHOW HERE WHEN BUTTON IS CLICK -------
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Divider />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} />
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Hidden>
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </PageContent>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}

TransactionPage.propTypes = {
  intl: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles))(TransactionPage);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you remove everything that is unrelated to the question in your sample code. Simply show the button and the item that should display the date. I suspect you want to set your state here, and pass it to another component as props when the user clicks.

Comment: You need to call an event when that Button clicked and then call `setState()` to set a state on `this.state = {}` and then use a {} for changing your view based on state changes

Comment: If you're new to 'this programming' do not jump into React or any other library/ framework... Pick a language (e.g Javascript) and stick with to learn it... Then the libs/frameworks will make much more sense as they are built on top of the fundamentals... They do not exist in a vacuum...

Answer (score 0):

Add an onClick-listener to your button with an anonymous function like

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ buttonClickedDate: new Date() }) ..></button>
```

And in your render method, where you want to output the date add

```
{this.state.buttonClickedDate}
```